# Getting data from a uri django

Tags: python, django, xml, django-rest-framework

I have a django view that takes in a json object and from that object I am able to get a uri. The uri contains an xml object. What I want to do is get the data from the xml object but I am not sure how to do this. I'm using django rest, which I am fairly inexperienced in using, but I do not know the uri until I search the json object in the view. I have tried parsing it in the template but ran into CORS issues amongst others. Any ideas on how this could be done in the view? My main issue is not so much parsing the xml but how to get around the CORS issue which I have no experience in dealing with

Answer (score 0):

You don't really do this in view part of Django.

What you should do is take the json, find the uri, get the content of uri through urllib, requests etc, get the relevant content from the response, add a new field to the json and then pass it to your view.